# Path not found in Executable Jar

Tags: java

I am currently adding a `VBS script` for `hMailServer` within my Java code to configure a server prior to starting my JavaMail client. All works via eclipse however when I export to an executable jar I think the file path is wrong. eg via eclipse I see `cscript C:\Users\username\Desktop\RadioWithEmail\target\classes\script\hmail-create-account1.vbs user password test.au`  which works perfectly.
From the executable jar I get
`cscript file:\C:\Users\username\Desktop\NeoChat.jar!\script\hmail-create-account1.vbs user password test.au`
Below is my code. What finger fault have I made regards getting the file path? Any advice welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
 public class emailLogin {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private PersistenceAccess persistenceAccess = new PersistenceAccess();

    private User me;
    private Settings settings;
    private EmailManager emailManager = new EmailManager(settings);
    private File f;

    private MainUiController ui;

    public emailLogin(Stage stage, final Settings settings, MainUiController ui) throws Exception {
        this.settings = settings;
        this.ui = ui;
        me = settings.getMe();
        String user = me.getNick();
        String ip = me.getIpAddress();
        String emailaddress = user + "@" + ip;
        /* Routine to bring the account onto hMailserver */
        f = new File(getClass().getResource("/script/hmail-create-account1.vbs").getFile());
        // String path = f.getPath();
        // String pathto =('"'+path+'"');
        System.out.println("cscript " + f + " " + user + " " + "password" + " " + ip);
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript " + f + " " + user + " " + "password" + " " + ip);

        ViewFactory viewFactory = new ViewFactory(emailManager);

        List<ValidAccount> validAccounts = persistenceAccess.loadFromPersistence();
        if (validAccounts.size() > 0) {
            viewFactory.showMainWindow(settings, ui);
            for (ValidAccount validAccount : validAccounts) {
                EmailAccount emailAccountupdate = new EmailAccount(validAccount.getAddress(),
                        validAccount.getPassword(), me.getIpAddress());
                LoginService loginService = new LoginService(emailAccountupdate, emailManager, settings, ui);
                loginService.start();
            }
        } else {
            viewFactory.showLoginWindow(settings, ui);
        }

    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {
        List<ValidAccount> validAccounts = new ArrayList<ValidAccount>();
        for (EmailAccount emailAccount : emailManager.getEmailAccounts()) {
            validAccounts.add(new ValidAccount(emailAccount.getAddress(), emailAccount.getPassword()));
        }
        persistenceAccess.savePersistence(validAccounts);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the paths be different for the two cases?  That is, do you want the .vbs script to be coming out of the .jar file?  I assume that `C:\Users\username\Desktop\NeoChat.jar` where the code is coming from when you run it as a .jar. If the answer is Yes, then what is the issue exactly?  That file is not being found in the .jar? You seem to say that the path is wrong.  How is it wrong?  What error message(s) are you getting? I think you explaining in more detail what is going on when you run it from the .jar would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Steve and apologies for any confusion, when I run from the jar the script is not found and run. It runs fine from within eclipse.  Your assumption of C:\Users\username\Desktop\NeoChat.jar for the jar is correct. Yes I want the script to be run from within the jar so it can be run on any machine. Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: Makes sense.  So then the question is why it isn't being found in the .jar.  For it to work, there has to be a directory named `scripts` on the classpath, and that directory has to contain the script `hmail-create-account1.vbs`.  Have you looked at what is actually in the .jar file?  Is the script where you expect it to be?  Ultimately, you should be able to diagnose this by printing out the classpath from inside your code or by viewing it in your debugger.  Then, looking at that result and the .jar's contents, it should be black and white as to what's going on.

Comment: can you do a f.exists() and check if the file exists after you've got it from resources. Additionally can you do jar tf your.jar and confirm if the file exists in jar. Moreover, I am not too sure if you will be allowed to execute a binary file from jar file without extracting it. My suggestion would be to place your resources along side the jar file and supply the resource as a command line to the jar and then run instead of bundling it with jar

Comment: Hi Steve, Yes I have several directories under the resource folder and one is called scripts where I have the script.  I also have a directory for my fxml files called fxml plus others eg icons etc. . I can see the file within the jar. Apologies Steve however, I am not sure what you mean by printing out the classpath from inside your code or by viewing it in your debugger as I am a newbie All the others work fine

Comment: I can run it fine from outside of the Jar. I was hoping not to do this as I just want a singular Jar file for ease